# C# Image uploading using FileUpload

Tags: c#, image

I found the following code but unable to understand what should I pass through `ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)`.

I need a FileUpload tool to upload an image to system and to pass it to `ImageToBase64`

For reference my code is

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

I tried doing `ImageToBase64(FileUpload.FileBytes, "Image/PNG")` But I am getting syntax error. What's the correct syntax that I can use to this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the function takes argument of type Image and ImageFormat, and you are passing in byte[] and string.

You don't need mime type, and you would only need the

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(FileUpload.FileBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! and is there any such simple methods to convert back `Base64String` to `Image` back?

Comment: Convert.FromBase64CharArray() should suffice.

Comment: Sorry Jishi I couldn't understand how to use `Convert.FromBase64CharArray()` to convert back `base64String` back to image.

Comment: IT will convert it back to an byte[] array, if you need it in an Image object, you need to create a Image or a Bitmap out of it. It all depends on what you plan on doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

As the method signature states, the second parameter is of type [ImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx). This is an enumeration, so you'd use it like so:

```
/// create or load a bitmap
var bitmap = new Bitmap(.....);

var base64string = ImageToBase64(bitmap,ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

In this case, the `ImageFormat` parameter is apparently used to tell the `Save()` method what format you'd like the data in (jpeg, png, bmp, etc). The MIME type is insufficient, and doesn't really belong in this context since this method isn't web-specific.

Comment: Where should I use FileUpload here? and what should I write in `new Bitmap(....);` ?

Comment: @Madcoder I assumed you were trying to convert an image you already had into a base 64 string, since that's what the method you posted does. If you already have a `FileUpload` that you've received from a form POST (probably in ASP.NET), you don't need to go through the base 64 encoding at all. What exactly are you trying to do??